# What is the maximum value of a “tinyint” field in most database systems?

Tags: c#, database

Like the header saiys, what is the maximum value of a “tinyint” field in most database systems? I've heard it may be 240 or 255?

Cheers

Comment: Define "most database systems". That being said, it's perhaps reasonable to assume that this type is implemented as an octet (i.e. an 8-bit byte), therefore the maximum value is likely to be either 2^7-1 = 127 (if the datatype is signed) or 2^8-1 = 255 (if unsigned).

Comment: Since there could be many such database engines, you are basically asking us to list all database engines with their interpretation of what `tinyint` means, which is off-topic on this site. Please ask about a specific database engine, or use Google to find relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What would be the sense of 240?

Tinyint is mostly represented as one byte. In all computers build since the 8 bit byte became standard that is a value of 0-255.

Comment: In MySql it is signed by default, which is why this question quickly becomes off-topic, there's no single right answer except for "list all the database engines and their definition of tinyint", which is off-topic.